# How to extract actions from Symfony Controllers?

Tags: php, symfony, decorator, php-5.3

I'm refactoring a not-so-complex website based on Symfony 2.2 / PHP 5.3, and the main issue here is repeated code.

There are two bundles, one for the main website, and another with the mobile version. Those differences are not only on templates and static files, as they comprise some differences in business rules and so on.

Currently those two bundles sport three controllers, one being the main guy, another being the exceptions controller, but a third is the "mother-controller", that holds several common methods and behaviours, and is inherited by the actual controllers.
This poses a small problem, since I can't simply make the action controllers of the mobile bundle inherit from the desktop bundle. All I could do is implement inheritance between the mobile's `DefaultController` and the desktop one... And thus I still have a bunch of actions almost equal, except for some custom lines.

Is there a way to extract those actions to a generic class and them import them into the controllers (like we have in Yii's Action classes)? I searched about using the decorator pattern to no avail, and was wondering if there's any sort of known method to implement this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two bundles my first idea would be to create another (let's call it "CoreBundle") and create `CommonController` there and put common logic into it. Then, let other controllers `extend` this `CommonController`.

The more cleaner, but harder, solution would be to create service which would be parametrized  by needed data/services.

Comment: I may not have made it clear enough, but the idea of the `CommonController` would not work since we already have a `DefaultController` that includes generic logic for the system - and it wouldn't make sense to include specific actions on it :(